# phpMyAdmin no relations on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

this is my first question here on StackOverflow so I hope I will do everything correct ;).

I have installed mysql & php my admin on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server with ISPConfig 3. At first everythings seemed to work perfect. But as soon I wanted to import my mysqldump from my local xampp installation I figured out that my relations have not been imported, when i tried to create them manually in phpMyAdmin I have seen that I got a lot of erros.

With the help of google i found out that i did not have had a phpmyadmin database so I downloaded the package to my desktop and imported the create_table.sql from the examples folder but nothing has changed, yet.

I am really kind of new to that configuration so I am not really sure if I am able to update manually.

Here are some Information about my Server:

DatabaseServer:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server-Typ: MySQL
Server Version: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protokoll-Version: 10
Benutzer: root@localhost
Server Zeichensatz: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Webserver:

```
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - 5.5.40
PHP-Erweiterung: mysqli Dokumentation
```

PhpMyAdmin:

```
Versionsinformationen: 4.0.10deb1
```

Sorry but I can only provide a german screenshot but i hope you can see whats going on ;)

(Because of not enough reputation points here a link to my screen)

http://s14.directupload.net/images/141017/nxdxi6md.png

Thank you for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the SQL file you imported, I can't tell why you didn't get relations on your imported tables, but the warning messages you're seeing aren't related. The messages are indeed telling you that the database that phpMyAdmin uses for some advanced features (such as bookmarking queries or the Designer interface), but that wouldn't affect the import.

Since you've used the package manager to install phpMyAdmin, it should handle creating and configuring the phpMyAdmin database for you. Try running `dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin` to force it to rerun the installation script.

Comment: I simple had to reconfigure / reinstall phpmyadmin. After that, everything went as wanted. Thank you :)